# unable to run firefox through jenkins?

Tags: firefox, jenkins

I am running robot framework through jenkins but when ever i am running the build, i get the firefox error

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Rocko/workspace

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/pradeekyahvi/robot.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/pradeekyahvi/robot.git
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git3401708129991506911.credentials # timeout=10
>   git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/pradeekyahvi/robot.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision 7a869c5dd37a5c5875c17651a060a7536662ff75 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f 7a869c5dd37a5c5875c17651a060a7536662ff75
>   First time build. Skipping changelog.
>   Triggering Rocko » firefox
>   Rocko » firefox completed with result FAILURE
>   Finished: FAILURE

I am using linux mint 17 and firefox 33.0.Jenkins version is 1.590.

Answer (score 1):

You did not state how you run Jenkins or what plugins you have configured, so I am assuming you are installed Jenkins using the package manager of your distribution and are running with Jenkins with defaults.

Firefox is a GUI application and it needs to connect to an X server to send it commands to draw windows and such. Usually Jenkins is set up to run as a background system daemon that has no access to any X server session.

There are X servers that draw into memory and need no access to graphics hardware. There are even Jenkins plugins to help you set up the build environment for a GUI process like Firefox.

These are [Xvfb plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin) and [Xvnc plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin). Xvfb plugin is maybe a bit easier to set up but Xvnc allows you to connect to the server to see what the GUI process is doing, which might be valuable for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of Jenkins refusing to launch GUI based programs when it was running as a service on Windows.
Running Jenkins via Command line solved the issue.